# Creating file takes time in bash

Tags: bash

I have a bash script in which I am doing string substitutions by taking input values different source files to create one complete string record. I have to create 5L such records in a file in 5mins on-the-go(records need to be written to the file as soon as it is created), however the script is very slow (20k records in 5mins). Below is the script I used.

```
#!/bin/bash


sampleRecod="__TIME__-0400 INFO    639582 truefile?apikey=__API_KEY__json||__STATUS__|34|0||0|0|__MAINSIZE__|1|"
count=0;
license_array=(`cat license.txt | xargs`)
status_array=(`cat status.json | xargs`)
error_array=(`cat 403.json | xargs`)
finalRes="";
echo $(date +"%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%3N")

while true;do
        time=$(date +'%Y-%m-%dT%T.%3N')
        line=${license_array[`shuf -i 0-963 -n 1`]}
        status=${status_array[`shuf -i 0-7 -n 1`]}
        responseMainPart=$(shuf -i 100-999 -n 1)
        if [ $status -eq 403 ] || [ $status -eq 0 ]
        then
                responseMainPart=${error_array[`shuf -i 0-3 -n 1`]}
        fi
       result=$(echo "$sampleRecod" | sed "s/__TIME__/$time/g")
       result=$(echo "$result" | sed "s/__KEY__/$line/g")
       result=$(echo "$result" | sed "s/__STATUS__/$status/g")
       result=$(echo "$result" | sed "s/__MAIN_SIZE__/$responseMainPart/g")
       finalRes+="${result} \n";
       count=$((count+1))
       if [ $count -eq 1000 ]
       then
               #echo "got count";
               count=0;
               echo -e $finalRes >> new_data_1.log;
               finalRes="";
       fi


done
echo -e $finalRes >> new_data_1.log;
echo $(date +"%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%3N")
```

Can anyone suggest how can I optimize this?? The files I am retrieving values do not have many lines as well.
I have tried replacing shuf with sed but still not much help.

Comment: If speed is important you shouldn't be using a shell script. Use a real programming language.

Comment: You're creating 4 new `sed` processes and some `shufs` for **every line**! That's very inefficient. You can do multiple edits in one go with multiple `-e` parameters `sed -e 's/a/b/' -e 's/f/g/' -e 's/k/l/'` at least.

Comment: Creating subprocesses is usually the slowest thing a shell script can do. Each `result=$(echo ... | sed ...)` line creates *three* subprocesses (one to run `echo`, one for `sed`, and one to manage the whole pipeline). It'd be much better to do as much as possible directly in the shell without using subprocess at all, like `result="${result//__KEY__/$line}"`. But even if you could eliminate *all* subprocesses from the loop, that might not be enough. As Barmar said, you really should be using a real programming language.

Comment: I know it's outside the loop and makes no difference whatsoever to the overall time, but even `echo $(date)` is creating a subprocess in which to run `date` as a further subprocess to pass the result to the third process running `echo`, when actually `date` would produce the same result with just one process.

Comment: My guess is that the `shuf` is killing you. You invoke it several times in each loop iteration, and each invocation of course means creation of a child process.  Also you call `sed` several times - ageinst child processes. Instead of creating child processes here, do everything inside your bash process.